# Exclude a grandchild from XML using XPath

Tags: sql-server, xpath

Trying to exclude a specific grandchild when reading an XML structure using SQL Server 2017.

I have an example structure as follows:

```
<root>
    <a id="parent">
        <b id = "child1">
            <c id = "grandchild1"/>
            <c id = "grandchild2"/>
        </b>
        <b id = "child2">
            <c id = "grandchild3"/>
            <c id = "grandchild4"/>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

I can exclude a specific child using `c[not(contains(@id,"grandchild3"))]` when I navigate to for example the node `<b id = "child2">`.

But how would I exclude that specific grandchild when processing the rest of the XML from the root node?

What i would like to receive, so I can write it to a file, is a structure like this:

```
<root>
    <a id="parent">
        <b id = "child1">
            <c id = "grandchild1"/>
            <c id = "grandchild2"/>
        </b>
        <b id = "child2">
            <c id = "grandchild4"/>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

As can be seen `grandchild3` is now missing from this structure.

Comment: Hi Thommy. Can you include in your question what specific result you wish to obtain?

Comment: As per request i have included an example of the desired output

Comment: So you want every node except the `c` node with an `id` of `grandchild3` ?

Comment: Correct! Every node except c node with an id of grandchild3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this in a `SELECT` is surprisingly involved, but fortunately you don't need that. You can make a copy of your xml, modify it with `.modify`, then use that:

```
declare @original xml = '<root>
    <a id="parent">
        <b id = "child1">
            <c id = "grandchild1"/>
            <c id = "grandchild2"/>
        </b>
        <b id = "child2">
            <c id = "grandchild3"/>
            <c id = "grandchild4"/>
        </b>
    </a>
</root>'

declare @new xml = @original

set @new.modify('delete //c[@id="grandchild3"]')

select @new
```

gives

```
<root>
  <a id="parent">
    <b id="child1">
      <c id="grandchild1" />
      <c id="grandchild2" />
    </b>
    <b id="child2">
      <c id="grandchild4" />
    </b>
  </a>
</root>
```

as desired.

The xpath `//c[@id="grandchild3"]` means "Any `c` node (anywhere in the document) with an `id` attribute with value `grandchild3`".

Comment: This worked perfectly. As you hinted i was experimenting with `SELECT` but it was very tricky. I was also unaware of modify()!